# Simplifying statements

Tags: java, intellij-idea, simplify

I am working on a project and I am using Intellij IDEA. While I was writing I got a notification that my if-statement could be simplified. (Note that I am still new to coding)

It says:

Reports if statements which can be simplified to single assignment or return statements.
For example:

```
if (foo()) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

can be simplified to

```
return foo();
```

How does this work?
Say foo() is the number 4, wouldn't this just return 4 instead of true? What am I misunderstanding?

**Edit**

Here is the code I am writing:

```
if (row > 0 && row < 4 && col > 0 && col < 4) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

and it can be simplified to:

```
return !(row > 0 && row < 4 && col > 0 && col < 4);
```

I just don't understand how this is simplified.

Comment: If `foo()` returned a number, it wouldn't work in the first example, since it requires a boolean value from the start.

Comment: How would `foo()` equal 4 work in `if(4)`?

Comment: As AntonH said: foo() has to return an boolean (true/false), than it works.

Comment: What is hard to understand that one line is simpler than a 5 line `if-else` that has the same effect?

Comment: After edit: if your condition fails at some point, it's implied value is `false`. Since you want it to return `true` in this case, you put a "not" `!` in front of it. In the same way, it it passes the contition, it's value is '`true`, which needs a "not" in front to return `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(row > 0 && row < 4 && col > 0 && col < 4)` is itself a boolean (true or false).

We can break it down as `boolean && boolean && boolean && boolean` as `<` and `>` operators return booleans. Likewise, a boolean and a boolean is a boolean, therefore the entire expression is a boolean and can be returned as such.

You can think about it as such:

- For the row, you have a number, so you can say "how many" or "which number". Same for the column.
- For the comparisons, you can ask: If x and y are numbers, then is x < y? The answers possible are `true` or `false`. Hence boolean.
- For `&&`, `||`, or `!`, you can ask yourself: "If a and b are statements (true or false), then "a and b are both true" is either true or false. Same for "or", or "a is not true". The results are true and false.

Now you can look at the if, and read it as "if **foo** is true, then return false. Otherwise, return true". This clearly simplifies to "return the opposite of **foo**" or, "return not **foo**".

Answer (score 1):

For an if statement to compile, the condition between parenthesis, has to be a boolean.

So, if you can put the method foo as the condition of an if, it's because it returns a boolean.

Therefore, you could write:

```
return foo();
```

In your particular case, the expression `!(row > 0 && row < 4 && col > 0 && col < 4)` evaluates to true or false, Therefore you could write:

```
return !(row > 0 && row < 4 && col > 0 && col < 4);
```

Comment: You are forgetting the `!` for his specific example.

Comment: True, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Except for the entire meaning of the condition ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your Foo() method returns a boolean value, so it will be true or false. Therefor, you do not need to add redundancy by adding an if statement to check for true or false, and then return true or false.

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code like you:

```
if (other.getClassAbbr().equals(this.getClassAbbr())
        && other.getInstance().equals(this.getInstance())) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

After thinking of it, I take the suggestion:
'if' statement can be simplified

Then the code be changed to:

```
    return other.getClassAbbr().equals(this.getClassAbbr())
            && other.getInstance().equals(this.getInstance());
```

Yes, code gets clean.